# Not able to call correct web api method with string parameter in odata query

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I don't have much experience with odata and I'm having trouble calling the correct method in my Angular app.  Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi1",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{FileName}",
                defaults: new { FileName = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This is in an AngularJS factory which uses $resource:

```
 getFileByName: { url: svcFileURL + "/GetUploadedFileByName(FileName = ':FileName')", method: "GET", withCredentials: true, responseType: 'arraybuffer' },
```

And here is my controller code:

```
 // GET: odata/UploadedFiles(name)
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<UploadedFile> GetUploadedFileByName([FromODataUri] string FileName)
        {

            return db.blah.Where(file => file.FileName == FileName);
        }
```

No matter how I try it I keep getting a 404.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Did you check in your network tab, how your request exactly looks like?

Comment: Yes, here's what it looks like:  /odata/UploadedFiles/GetUploadedFileByName(FileName='Tulips.jpg')